# Configuring email in PHP for Elgg using postfix

Tags: ubuntu, php, postfix

I am trying to setup PHP for running Elgg.

I have PHP 5.5 installed in a Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox VM. I need to complete the following requirement ([elgg requirements page](http://learn.elgg.org/en/1.x/intro/install.html)) :

```
Proper configuration and ability to send email through an MTA
```

I tried searching and found a related [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/47618).

I tried running :

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

The explanation of the options is slightly different from the other answer :

[image]

I'm not sure which is the best option to complete this. I tried selecting Satellite option. What should I specify in the system mail name ? I am very new to this .. please help.

[image]

Can someone please tell what is the most reliable way to configure postfix for completing this requirement ?

Comment: What do you want your mail server to do for you? Please specify your requirements in detail

Comment: I am trying to setup Elgg. You can see requirements link I shared. I know as much as that requirements page is asking and I am trying to figure it out. Elgg probably needs to be able to send an email through PHP while running on a web server.

Comment: I dont think you need any special configuration for your `postfix` server to send out mails. For testing just install and start the server. Montior `/var/log/mail.log` for errors.

Comment: What mode would you recommend ? Do you think I need to complete all the steps mentioned here : http://askubuntu.com/a/47618/26672 ?

Comment: You can use `internet site` for now.

Comment: OK I'll try that. Will post if I get stuck ! Thanks !